# Swift UI older version iOS view not in full screen

Tags: swift, view, frame, fullscreen

Where is notes row's that frame not going bigger, in iOS 16 that section from navigation bar till "add note" "TextField", but in older version I cannot fill that space under navigation bar, if I put ".frame" that view expands but in the bottom, also and to much, "Spacer()" also not helping. Where can be problem?
This part of code also in "NAvigationView" and "VStack" with buttons bellow

```
               VStack {
                    Divider()
                    List {
                        ForEach(habit.aboutHabit?.components(separatedBy: "\n") ?? [], id: \.self) { description in
                            Text(description)
                        }
                        .onDelete { indices in
                            if let currentDescriptions = habit.aboutHabit?.components(separatedBy: "\n") {
                                let updatedDescriptions = currentDescriptions.enumerated().compactMap { index, description in
                                    !indices.contains(index) ? description : nil
                                }
                                habit.aboutHabit = updatedDescriptions.joined(separator: "\n")
                                try? moc.save()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                     Divider()
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Add Note.", text: $aboutHabitTemp)
                            .font(.body)
                            .padding(.vertical, 9)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                            .cornerRadius(9)
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                if !aboutHabitTemp.isEmpty {
                                    if let currentDescription = habit.aboutHabit {
                                        habit.aboutHabit = "\(currentDescription)\n\(aboutHabitTemp)"
                                    } else {
                                        habit.aboutHabit = aboutHabitTemp
                                    }
                                    aboutHabitTemp = ""
                                    try? moc.save()
                                }
                            }
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        }
                        .disabled(aboutHabitTemp.isEmpty)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 9)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
```

[**Screenshot from view here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB0BE.png)

Tried add frame Maxheight .infinity, but nothing changes, then just height: 350 or 450 but expands in the bottom and top, what's bad.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: where is in screen shot top Divider in newer iOS versions that Divider under navigation bar, but in older it is space between navigation bar and that divider.